# QuickSight add subset of fields

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Total AWS QuickSight newbie here. I'm trying to import some cost data in CSV form into QuickSight and add some calculated fields.

The data I have is of the form:

| Type | Units Consumed |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 5 |

... and so on

`Unit Cost ($)` is not part of the dataset and is something like

| Unit Cost | Amount ($) |
| --- | --- |
| Unit Cost (A) | 1 |
| Unit Cost (B) | 2 |

I would like to compute (either as part of the dataset or as part of an analysis visual, maybe) the total costs for A and B as separate line items. Something like

```
Total Cost (A) = Sum(Amount where Type = A) * Unit Cost (A)
Total Cost (B) = Sum(Amount where Type = B) * Unit Cost (B)
```

Here are the things I've tried which don't work:

```
sumOver({Units Consumed}, Type='A')
sumIf({Units Consumed}, Type='A')
```

To break it down and test smaller parts, I added a calculated field which simply does

```
sum({Units Consumed})
```

But it just adds a column to the dataset with every field as "Undefined".

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the code

```
sumIf({Units Consumed}, Type='A')
```

and it worked. Could you check if Units Consumed is a integer column type?

[How to change column type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/changing-a-field-data-type.html)